# Add a button to new mail window MS outlook (next to send)

Tags: c#, email, outlook, visual-studio-2015, vsto

How can I add a Textbox and Label (like CC, To...) to new mail window MS outlook (next to send)?

I use Visual Studio 2015 and VSTO 2016

If it is possible, so how can I personalize the send button script?

[The image mentor my desire button location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtPE4.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only add new controls to the ribbon, not next to the Send button.